# C++ SFML clock crazy output

Tags: c++, sfml

I already tried to restart my program or created new ones, but I never get a valid time, I always get something like 5e-06 as output for seconds... Where is the Problem? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3sGy.png
Thanks for help already

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
sf::Clock clock;

sf::Time time1 = clock.getElapsedTime();

sf::Time time2 = clock.restart();

sf::RenderWindow myWindow(sf::VideoMode(512, 512), "SFML Window", sf::Style::Default | sf::Style::Titlebar);
while (myWindow.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event openEvent;

    std::cout << time1.asSeconds() << std::endl;
    while (myWindow.pollEvent(openEvent))
    {
        switch (openEvent.type)
        {
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            myWindow.close();
            break;
            myWindow.clear();
            myWindow.display();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "5e-06" is "five times ten to the power of negative six" -   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Answer (score 2):

You create the clock and in the next instruction you get the elapsed time (nanoseconds?). Then you convert it to seconds (0.000005) and the representation is that (5e-06)

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the time outside the loop. Try moving clock.getElapsedTime() inside the loop before you output it.